# swift 4 - Parsing json to struct (codable), but with an extra variable which is not from json

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I am currently getting all the data I want from my json, but I want to add extra variable which is not from the json.

```
struct LoanUser: Codable {
let name: String
let use: String
let location: Location
let loan_amount: Int
let image: Image
var favorite: Bool = false
```

}

The     var favorite: bool = false is not a json string. This is the extra variable I want added

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify coding keys by yourself and do not include favorite

```
struct LoanUser: Codable {
    let name: String
    let use: String
    let location: Location
    let loan_amount: Int
    let image: Image
    var favorite: Bool = false

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, use, location, loan_amount, image
    }
}
```